# How can I advance a warpriest beyond level 20?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

So, my warpriest has reached level 20, and my DM is telling me that is the highest I can go, so I have to either start with another class or find a prestige class - any suggestions?

Comment: This is far too broad to answer. You'll need to add in some details about your Warpriest and what you're hoping to accomplish by advancing them further for us to be able to give you targeted advicel.

Comment: @ObliviousSage [Pathfinder contains rules for characters over level 20](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement#Advancing_Beyond_20th_Level) (PF CRB, pg 406-407). Admittedly they are not very detailed rules, but they provide the necessary framework to adjudicate further advancement if desired. (these rules would assume the character can continue advancing in the same class, so I suspect the DM in this case is not referencing them.)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @Carcer Actually the last section in those rules indicate that the simplest approach is to treat level 20 as the cap for class level but not for character level. As the OP indicated their DM said they needed to either multiclass or start a prestige class, that's probably the route they're going.

Comment: @ObliviousSage fair point, I'd neglected that bit of it. We all learned a thing today!